# Android Studio: Inline compiler showing red errors only for Flavor specific Kotlin files, but compilation with gradle works fine

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, syntax-error, android-productflavors

I know similar questions exist already. But my case seems different. I have these inline compiler error ONLY in the files that are Flavor specific; added in `"...\src\myFlavor\..."`.  And even the basic classes are not found, check the image attached in the end. When I run the app, it compiles and runs fine.

I have tried these steps already:

- File > Invalidate Cache/Restart > Invalidate and Restart
- Delete two files .gradle and .idea
- Remove dependency which is showing error & Sync. Again add dependency & Sync.

I even did a fresh install of Android Studio on another laptop and pulled my code there. Nothing resolves this.

I have more than 5 flavors in my app.

I am using the following versions of gradle, kotlin and Android studio.

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20"

api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.20"

Android Studio: Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
```

This issue is old, I was living with it. So now I added this question here. Please help me with it. It makes development very hard on these files.

[image]

Comment: hmm, maybe a stupid question, but: Android Studio is always focused on only 1 selection of "buildType + flavor". You can see the currently selected "Build Variant" in the tab with that name. Did you check that the file you have open is indeed part of the flavor that is currently selected under "Build Variants" in Android Studio?

Comment: @muetzenflo yes the files are specific for the same flavor that is selected under "Active Build Variant" (good point though)

Comment: share the gradle file?

Comment: I'd suggest adding flavor specific sources in the gradle perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported the issue and Android team guided me.

I installed [Android Studio Flamingo](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview) and the issue got resolved.

I didnt know there was a new version out there cz I used to "check for updates" and it said u have the latest version.